# mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link

Tags: php, mysql

I just hosted my self-training site and now i am getting this warning. I know that I must not have had warning notifications turned on so now this is showing up. How can fix it.
You can have a look at the warning message over at this [site](http://padfootpak.host22.com)

here is my php code

```
<html>
<?php
require("db_connect.php");

    ?>
<head>
    <title>Instant Blog</title>
<link href='images/home.ico' rel='icon' type='image/vnd.microsoft.icon'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="postsContainer">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "<p class=\"postedText\">" . $row['post'] . "</p>";
              }
$something = mysql_close($db_conn); //Warning points here.
?>
</div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <textarea rows="10" name = "blogText" cols="150" class="blogBox"></textarea>
            <input type="image" src="images/button.png" name="btnPost" value="Post" class="postButton" style="" padding-top: 2px;/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `var_dump($db_conn)` to see *what* it is.

Comment: Check db_connect.php if the connection is really called $db_conn. Also, why do you define it to a variable? Just call `mysql_close($db_conn);`. I also suggest you read the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Comment: @Griffin yeah the problem was the variable name. and were you the one who posted "Whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatt"?

Comment: @Prometheus87 No, I didn't post "Whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatt". Glad I could help.

Comment: Griffin guess it was @Jon then

Comment: @Prometheus87 I posted "Whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone misses out on the comments in the original post, the problem was that the variable `$db_conn` was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> ### PHP.net : mysql-close
>
> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

You do not have to use, but `$db_conn` this should be `$db_conn = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

```
$db_conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

mysql_close($db_conn);
```

You are not closing `$db_conn` from the `db_connect.php`.